# PasteSpecial в Word используя win32com

Tags: windows, python-3.x, winapi, com, ms-word

Помогите разобраться: имею в буфере скопированные ячейки из Excell, никак не могу сделать специальную вставку в Word. Вот кусок кода:

```
        xl.Run("PERSONAL.xlsb!Macros1") #запуск макроса в открытом Excel
        xl.ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Select() #выбираем все ячейки
        xl.Selection.Copy() #копируем в буфер
        word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
        word.Documents.Open('12345.doc') #запускаем нужный документ
        word.Selection.Find.Text = 'some_word' #ищем слово, которое надо заменить
        word.Selection.Find.Execute()
        word.Selection.PasteSpecial() #Тут заменяем что искали на содержимое буфера со специальной вставкой
```

Проблема собственно в последней строчке, не знаю какой параметр передать, чтобы вставилось с нужным форматированием (в моем случае нужно PasteAsImage). На англоязычном форуме задавали подобный вопрос для вставки в Excel, человек смог решить прописав **xl.Selection.PasteSpecial(Paste=constants.xlPasteValues)**, но с Вордом у меня это не прокатило. Думаю, что подсказку стоит искать здесь [ссылка 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff191763.aspx) и здесь [ссылка 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197265.aspx), но всё равно ничего не получается. Если передаю параметр из второй ссылки, например вот так: **word.Selection.PasteSpecial(DataType=4)**, все равно вставляется в исходном форматировании.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге решил зайти немного с другой стороны. Вместо "Вставить как картинку", использовал "Копировать как картинку" и потом методом Paste вставил всё содержимое. На выходе получилось следующее:

```
    xl.Run("PERSONAL.xlsb!Macros1") #запуск макроса в открытом Excel
    xl.ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Select() #выбираем все ячейки
    xl.Selection.CopyPicture() #копируем в буфер уже как картинку
    word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
    word.Documents.Open('12345.doc') #запускаем нужный документ
    word.Selection.Find.Text = 'some_word' #ищем слово, на место которого надо вставить скопированное из Excel
    word.Selection.Find.Execute()
    word.Selection.Paste() #Вставляем содержимое буфера (картинку)
```

Answer (score 0):

Да, ответ надо искать по второй ссылке. Там чётко прописаны все варианты, и ничего похожего на PasteAsImage там нет. Кстати, и у Excel тоже ([линк](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837425.aspx)).

Вариантов несколько. Можно установить линк на нужный Range, а не копировать его. Можно копировать в объект "таблица Excel". Остальные варианты сложнее.

**UPD:** Макрорекордер считает, что надо вот так:

```
Sub Макрос1()
    Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
End Sub
```

Но это в Офисе-2003. Другого счас под рукой нету.

Comment: Я не имел ввиду, что ищу метод непосредственно с названием PasteAsImage, я хотел описать, в каком формате мне нужна вставка. Какой ключ из ссылки ни использую, все равно вставляется без форматирования.

Comment: А о каком форматировании тогда идёт вообще речь, если Вы хотите вставить КАК КАРТИНКУ? тогда надо не Range в клипборд брать, а скриншот.

Comment: Не надо никакой скриншот брать. Скопируйте в экселе несколько ячеек и в ворде нажмите Вставить каа картинку-ячейки вставятся как изображение. Именно это мне и надо сделать.

Comment: Ну так проделайте это и запишите макрорекордером...